# Using Next-Auth with Credentials - How to redirect after login and signOut using the default page?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I've spent the whole day trying to work this out, but I am still unable.

I simply want, from the landing page, to have a "login" button that sends to the default credential login page.
On successful login, sends to the URL I want.
When signing out, user is redirected to the login screen.

The problem is that if I decide to define the callback.redirect, this applies to both signIn() and signOut() functions used on Client-Side.

I have also tried to use the signIn() function on Client side, as such, on the `pages/index.ts`

```
<button onClick={
     () =>
     signIn('credentials', {
     callbackUrl: '/dashboard/beers'
     }
}>Login test</button>
```

But it won't work if I don't give them the credentials in the options at the same time as the callback url. (password and email). If I put it in this way, and click on this button, it just send me to the error page to this URL `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error?error=Invalid%20Login`

I see a lot of questions regarding using our own custom pages, which I think I'd understand. But I don't see much information using just their built-in form.

For reference, here is my `[...nextauth].ts` code.

```
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GithubProvider from "next-auth/providers/github";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import getDbCollection from "../../../../lib/getCollection";
import { UserData } from "../../../types/users";
import { useUserStore } from "../../../stores/user";
import { JWT } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { redirect } from "next/dist/server/api-utils";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
    // Configure one or more authentication providers
    providers: [
        GithubProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID as string,
            clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET as string,
        }),
        // ...add more providers here
        CredentialsProvider({
            // The name to display on the sign in form (e.g. "Sign in with...")
            name: "Credentials",
            // `credentials` is used to generate a form on the sign in page.
            // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
            // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
            // You can pass any HTML attribute to the <input> tag through the object.
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "user@example.ca" },
                password: { label: "Password", type: "password" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {

                // Add logic here to look up the user from the credentials supplied. We will check against the DB see if the user's exist.
                const collection = await getDbCollection("users");
                // const user = { id: "1", name: "J Smith", email: "jsmith@example.com" };
                const { email, password } = credentials as {
                    email: string;
                    password: string;
                };
                try {
                    const user = await collection.findOne({ $and: [{ email: credentials?.email }, { pwd: credentials?.password }] }) as UserData;
       

                    if (!user
                    ) {
                        // If you return null then an error will be displayed advising the user to check their details.
                        throw new Error("Invalid Login");
                        // return null;
                    }
                    // else {
                    // Maybe not needed with session info
                    // setUserInfo(user);
                    // Any object returned will be saved in `user` property of the JWT
                    return {
                        id: user?._id as string,
                        name: user.name,
                        email: user.email,
                        role: user.role,
                        domain: user.domain
                        // ...user
                    };

                    // You can also Reject this callback with an Error thus the user will be sent to the error page with the error message as a query parameter
                    // }
                } catch (error) {
                    throw new Error("Invalid Login");
                }
            },
        })
    ],
    // TODO: try without?
    session: {
        strategy: 'jwt'
    },
    callbacks: {
        async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {

            if (user) {
                // return Promise.resolve('/dashboard/beers');
                // return '/dashboard/beers';
                return true;
            } else {
                // Return false to display a default error message
                // return false;
                // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
                return '/';
            }

        },

        async jwt({ token, user }: { token: JWT, user?: any | UserData; }) {
            // update token
            if (user?.role) {
                token.role = user.role;
            }
            if (user?.domain) {
                token.domain = user.domain;
            }
            // return final token
            return token;
        },
        async session({ session, token, user }: { session: any, token: JWT, user: any; }) {
            if (token.role) (session.user.role = token.role);
            if (token.domain) session.user.domain = token.domain;
            return session;
        },

        // async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
        //     return baseUrl + '/dashboard/beers';
        // },
    },

    // secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    // To customize our pages
    // pages: {
    //     signIn: '/auth/signin',
    // error: '/auth/error',
    // signOut: '/auth/signout'
    // }
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

If you need any other information, please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

To use my credentials and the proper callbackUrl I wanted on the singIn() function, I worked it out like this:

```
<button onClick={() =>
                  signIn('Credentials', {
                    callbackUrl: '/dashboard/beers'
                  }
                  )}
                >Login test</button>
```

It sends properly to the default login page with the callback desired. Note the first capital letter that changed from my problem before.

Next, my issue is that the signOut() function would not redirect to my signIn() page with the proper callback. I managed to work it out like this:

```
onClick: () => signOut(
            {
                callbackUrl: '/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=/dashboard/beers'
            }

        )
```

Which sends to the same link as my signIn().

But now I am facing another issue... which will be another question!! ^^'